# Will "Pop all as unstaged" overwrite or merge previous pulls?

Tags: git, visual-studio

If I have a bunch of changes in my branch and I choose `Stash All` from the Team Explorer screen in Visual Studio.  Then I do a git pull from master to get the lastest changes from master.  If now, I do a `Pop all as unstaged` from Team explorer, will it merge my unstaged changes with those from my previous pull or overwrite them?

Comment: When you do a stash pop it will try to do a proper merge. If there are conflicts it will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

`git stash pop` applies the *changes* (between the commit from which the stash was created, and the stash) to the worktree.  I'm not sure how this is implemented, but its basically equivalent to merging the stash into the commit you would get if you immediately committed your index (using the stash's parent commit as the merge base).